# Browse Field Data contains value but nothing is shown on the report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have annoying issue with CR 2011. We are trying to upgrade from very old CR8.5 (DBF files are used as source(s) for the reports) to CR2011 and right now strange issue has appeared.

There are several fields on the report and all of them contain some data (as can be seen in the dbf file itself and/or in Browse Field Data) but few of them are never "shown" on the report. (If I, however, browse the data within the preview in CR2011 designer, I can see the data with no problem.)

- This report uses two (non-linked) tables.
- If I try to create a blank report, add these two tables & format the report again, I'll get what I expect (i.e. all fields shown on the report). (But this is not a solution as we have hundreds of reports.)
- It does not matter if I (re)save report in latest format.
- Everything is shown when using CR8.5 (designer or "runtime")

Has anyone experienced similar behavior and/or some tips where to look?

Comment: It seems that something has changed significantly inside CR's dealing with report that contains multiple starting points (i.e. two unlinked tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-linked tables are "less" supported than before (whole support for dbf files is limited). So the only correct solution is to link non-linked tables together. In my case, as the "free" table was parameter table. I had to simply add "paramid" to both tables (always set to 0) and perform the linking.